# Changing the emitterPosition of a CAEmitterLayer and animating it

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit, particles

I'm currently having a SpriteKit particle animation representing a comet. What I wanna do now is change the EmitterPosition and animate it towards the center of my view. As a starting position I chose the upper right corner so it looks like if the comet is falling down. At first, I tried to do that using a CABasicAnimation: (Swift 5, Xcode 13.2.1)

```
let fromPoint : CGPoint = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.maxX, y: self.view.frame.minY)
let toPoint : CGPoint = self.view.center

let movement = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "movement")
movement.isAdditive = true
movement.fromValue =  NSValue(cgPoint: fromPoint)
movement.toValue =  NSValue(cgPoint: toPoint)
movement.duration = 5

particlesLayer.add(movement, forKey: "movement")
```

But this doesn't work. I originally set the position of the emitter to be

`particlesLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x:view.frame.maxX, y:view.frame.minY)`

and that's the place it just stays in and doesn't move. I've checked on multiple sites if this question was already answered and only found one post in Objective-C which was from ten years ago. Here is my full configuration of the particle animation:

```
        let size = view.bounds
        let host = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        bg.addSubview(host) // My background image I added the animation to.
        
        let particlesLayer = CAEmitterLayer()
        particlesLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)

        host.layer.addSublayer(particlesLayer)
        host.layer.masksToBounds = true

        particlesLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0).cgColor
        particlesLayer.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerCircle
        particlesLayer.emitterPosition = CGPoint(x:view.frame.maxX, y:view.frame.minY)
        particlesLayer.emitterSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
        particlesLayer.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerSurface
        particlesLayer.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive



        let image1 = UIImage(named: "Spark")?.cgImage

        let cell1 = CAEmitterCell()
        cell1.contents = image1
        cell1.name = "Comet"
        cell1.birthRate = 750.0
        cell1.lifetime = 12.0
        cell1.velocity = 79.0
        cell1.xAcceleration = 280.0
        cell1.yAcceleration = -308.0
        cell1.emissionLongitude = 262.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell1.emissionRange = 360.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell1.spinRange = 314.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell1.scale = 0.2
        cell1.scaleRange = 1.77
        cell1.scaleSpeed = -0.673
        cell1.alphaSpeed = -0.18
        cell1.color = UIColor(red: 41.0/255.0, green: 46.0/255.0, blue: 45.0/255.0, alpha: 0.39).cgColor

        let image2 = UIImage(named: "Spark")?.cgImage

        let cell2 = CAEmitterCell()
        cell2.contents = image2
        cell2.name = "Comet2"
        cell2.birthRate = 400.0
        cell2.lifetime = 1.3
        cell2.lifetimeRange = 1.5
        cell2.velocity = 79.0
        cell2.xAcceleration = 280.0
        cell2.yAcceleration = -308.0
        cell2.emissionLongitude = 262.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell2.emissionRange = 360.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell2.spinRange = 1272.0 * (.pi / 180.0)
        cell2.scale = 0.08
        cell2.scaleRange = 1.77
        cell2.scaleSpeed = -0.673
        cell2.alphaSpeed = -0.18
        cell2.color = UIColor(red: 62.8/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.39).cgColor

        particlesLayer.emitterCells = [cell1, cell2]
```

The CABasicAnimation is placed directly after that in my code.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll have more luck using `SKAction.follow(...)`. here is a particle emitter node that follows a path from a random position to the center of the screen. note: you must create your own `Comet.sks` file in the particle editor

```
import SpriteKit

class Comet: SKNode {
    var emitter:SKEmitterNode? = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Comet.sks")
    
    func launch() {
        //these coords assume `scene.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)`
        let half_x = (self.scene?.view?.frame.width ?? 0)/2
        let half_y = (self.scene?.view?.frame.height ?? 0)/2
        let startx = CGFloat.random(in: -half_x...half_x)
        let starty = CGFloat.random(in: -half_y...half_y)
        let endx = 0
        let endy = 0

        //PATH
        let cgMutablePath = CGMutablePath()
        cgMutablePath.move(to: CGPoint(x: startx, y: starty))
        cgMutablePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: endx, y: endy))

        // PARTICLE EMITTER
        emitter?.targetNode = self
        self.addChild(emitter ?? SKNode())
        
        //run action
        let follow = SKAction.follow(cgMutablePath, asOffset:true, orientToPath:true, speed: 400)
        follow.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.easeOut
        let die  = SKAction.run{ [weak self] in self?.die() }
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([ follow, die ])
        self.run(sequence)
    }
    
    func die() {
        self.removeAllActions()
        self.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But unfortunately, the comet I created in the code above cannot be created the same way using the particle editor. (Unless there is some way to convert such code into a .sks file I don't know of).